# Create an Entity Record using "Xrm.WebApi.createRecord" in JS- Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, webapi, dynamics-365

I was trying to create an entity record using `Xrm.WebApi.CreateRecord` but I'm getting the following error.

**"cannot find record to be updated"**

please note that the field 'edm_donorid' exists in the form and the ID that I'm using to fill the fill also exists in the contacts.

```js
var entity = {};
var type = result["_edm_donorid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.associatednavigationproperty"];

if (type == "edm_DonorID_contact") {
    entity["edm_DonorID_contact@odata.bind"] = "/contacts(" + result["_edm_donorid_value"] + ")";
}
else if (type == "edm_DonorID_account") {
    entity["edm_DonorID_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(" + result["_edm_donorid_value"] + ")";
}

opener.Xrm.WebApi.createRecord("edm_bookreceiptdetail", entity)
    .then(function success(record) {
        console.log("record created with ID: " + record.id);
        // perform operations on record creation
    },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            // handle error conditions
        }
    );
```

Comment: 100% sure this message is from the `console.log` in the error handling function? If yes, do you have any code running in the background, e.g. plugins?

Comment: yes, this message is from the console.log function. I have plugins that are running in the background

Comment: The plugin trace log can probably give you more details. You can also disable all plugin steps and try again. Finally in JavaScript the error object sometimes gives more useful details, apart from the message property.

Comment: check if you can create the record with Dataverse REST Builder https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB if you get an error also there probably there is something else causing the issue. Note that Xrm.WebApi syntax can be executed only with the managed solution version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and I fixed it.

**"cannot find record to be updated"** error comes when I disregarded filling fields that have a relation with another entity.

so, make sure to fill every mandatory field or fields related to any other entities when you create an entity record using JS.

Amer Azzam,
Microsoft Dynamics 365 Developer